# UIGestureRecognizer called on ViewX even though it's only on ViewY

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, uidatepicker

I have a View and 3 other Views on it but only the viewPushDatum View is relevant for my question. When the viewPushDatum is on the screen and I tap anywhere on it, nothing should happen and that works fine but I also have an UIDatePicker on the viewPushDatum and when I click on that the view disappears. I have one UIGestureRecognizer that is supposed to hide my viewPushDatum but I only want to hide viewPushDate when something is clicked somewhere outside of this view. I tried adding touch.view == myUIDatePicker to the function below but this didn't work and I tried touch.accessibilityFrame but I didn't get it to work. Does Anyone know how to change the code so that the gestureRecognizer is only called outside of my viewPushDatum?

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {

    if (touch.view == viewPushDatum) {
        return NO;
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {

UIView *pushDatumView;
if ((int)[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)
{
    //iPhone 5
    pushDatumView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -224+568, 320, 224)];


} else if ((int)[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 480) {
    //iPhone 4
    pushDatumView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -224+480, 320, 224)];
}

CGPoint aPoint = [touch locationInView:viewPushDatum];
BOOL isPointInsideView = [pushDatumView pointInside:aPoint withEvent:nil];


if (isPointInsideView == TRUE) {
    return NO;
} else {
    return YES;
}
}
```

This works for me now. Thanks though

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using view tags? You can set a tag for every view. 
    if (touch.view.tag == viewPushDatumTag) // viewPushDatumTag could be a #define